# why the NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() method always returns true,when i debug it on my windows phone 7 device?

Tags: windows-phone-7, networking

why the NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()  method always returns true,when i debug it on my windows phone 7 device?not emulator,is it sure that "NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType==NetworkInterface.None" means a device does't  get network access?how can i detect whether a device connected a network that has intenert access? i tried this link,[Zune-Detection-and-Network-Awareness](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121737/Zune-Detection-and-Network-Awareness),but the  NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()  method always returns true,which stumbled me a lot.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation for the method. Here is what [MSDN has to say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> A network connection is considered to be available if any network
>   interface is marked "up" and is not a loopback or tunnel interface.
>
> There are many cases in which a device or computer is not connected to
>   a useful network but is still considered available and
>   **GetIsNetworkAvailable** will return **true**. For example, if the device
>   running the application is connected to a wireless network that
>   requires a proxy, but the proxy is not set, **GetIsNetworkAvailable** will
>   return **true**. Another example of when **GetIsNetworkAvailable** will return
>   **true** is if the application is running on a computer that is connected
>   to a hub or router where the hub or router has lost the upstream
>   connection.

Generally, you could say that this method is generally prone to errors. I would recommend taking the approach of failed requests - have a couple of URLs to test against and check if HTTP/DNS resolve requests go through. If some of them pass - there is a connection. If all fail - chances are you are not connected.

[Here is a sample](http://sorokoletov.com/2012/04/quick-way-check-internet-available-windowsphone/).

Comment: However, attempting a service call will tend to introduce a noticeable delay to the user, in fact this lack of network awareness is one of my pet gripes with a great many software products.